# UnitTest C# VS15

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

I have a VS15 solution containing a Class Library project (a dll to test) and a Unit Test project with all the tests to run.
I could only run each test separately, but I want to visualize the UnitTest tab instead, to have a global view of my test. 
In according to MSDN guidelines, this tab should appear after the building phase, but it's not happening. 
How can I display that tab?

Comment: In menu : Test > Windows > Test explorer. (If my memory serves me well.)

Comment: I was searching it under "View" > Windows. Thanks a lot

Comment: I also added it as answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In menu : Test > Windows > Test explorer.

[image: menuitem]

More info on Microsoft docs : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/getting-started-with-unit-testing